# Using signals in c

Tags: c, signals

I was writing a simple program in c where via fork i create i child process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int handler(){

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    pid_t c=fork();
    if(c>0){
        sleep(1);
        printf("f:pid is %d \n",getpid());
        kill(c,SIGINT);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    if(c==0){
        pause();
        signal(SIGINT,handler);
        printf("child:pid is %d \n",getpid());
    }
}
```

The problem is that the child prints nothing. I thought that pause just waits for a signal to unpause the process and i can't understand why the print never happens.Any ideas?

Comment: Likely c = -1, the fork failed. Check for that.

Comment: Your signal handler function does not have the correct type.  In addition to returning an `int`, it must accept one argument of type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up the handler *before* you pause. Otherwise, `pause()` will be interrupted by the signal, then the default action of the signal will be taken, which is to terminate the process. It will never add the handler because the process is killed first.

```
    if(c==0){
        signal(SIGINT,handler);
        pause();
        printf("child:pid is %d \n",getpid());
    }
```

Comment: In fact, even that's not enough, as it produces a race between the parent calling `kill()` and the child calling `signal()`.  The *parent* should register the handler, before it forks, so that the registration is inherited by the child.  That way, the signal cannot be delivered before the child is ready for it.  Alternatively, the parent could block the signal before forking, and the child could use `sigsuspend()` instead of `pause()`.

Comment: True. While not completely reliable, the parent's `sleep(1);` is presumably intended to allow time for the child to establish the handler.